# Connect four javascript game issue

Tags: javascript

I have the following code
http://jsfiddle.net/zander_pope/307n91bj/

and this is the isVictory function:

```
function isVictory(placedX, placedY) {
  var i, j, x, y, maxX, maxY, steps, count = 0,
    directions = [
      { x: 0, y: 1  }, // North-South
      { x: 1, y: 0  }, // East-West
      { x: 1, y: 1  }, // Northeast-Southwest
      { x: 1, y: -1 }  // Southeast-Northwest
    ];

  // Check all directions
  outerloop:
  for (i = 0; i < directions.length; i++, count = 0) {
    // Set up bounds to go 3 pieces forward and backward
    x =     Math.min(Math.max(placedX - (3 * directions[i].x), 0), circle.length    - 1);
    y =     Math.min(Math.max(placedY - (3 * directions[i].y), 0), circle[0].length - 1);
    maxX =  Math.max(Math.min(placedX + (3 * directions[i].x),     circle.length    - 1), 0);
    maxY =  Math.max(Math.min(placedY + (3 * directions[i].y),     circle[0].length - 1), 0);
    steps = Math.max(Math.abs(maxX - x), Math.abs(maxY - y));

    for (j = 0; j < steps; j++, x += directions[i].x, y += directions[i].y) {
      if (circle[x][y] == circle[placedX][placedY]) {
        // Increase count
        if (++count >= 4) {
        return true;
          break outerloop;
        }
      } else {
        // Reset count
        count = 0;
      }
    }
  }

  //return count >= 4;
}
```

The issue is that it doesn't check the southeast-northwest direction.
Can you point me what is wrong?

Comment: You may want to explain which direction `northweast` is. :)

Comment: bottom right to top left

Comment: I just tried a couple of quick games on your jsfiddle - both diagonals ended up with a successful victory check

Comment: tried again. bottom-right to top-left doesn't work.

Comment: [Works for me](http://imgur.com/2TfstUp) - both when the last one placed is at the top or bottom of the slope.  Looks like you have a more subtle bug somewhere.

Comment: what browser do you use?

Comment: Chrome 43.0.2357.81 m

Comment: [Cannot Read Property '4' of undefined](http://gyazo.com/e01f2316ab469dfbbef8c3b6989fa2e0) when I drop the blue token in the far right side ( that was the last one I dropped ). Anything dropped on the far right afterwards reports same error. Cannot win after the error occurs.
Chrome shows the error @ 'isVictory - 153', 'checkPlace - 83', 'onclick - 183'. Using Chrome 43.0.2357.81 m

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the 3rd slot on the far right side which throws the undefined error from above.

Comment: Yes and its not only that. Even if the error is not thrown the validation for the bottom-right to top-left doesn't work properly.

Comment: I wasn't having any issues with winning from bot-right to top-left before I ran into the error.

Comment: @Press Could you help me out debugging this and teach me what I did wrong?